# Can't align 2 views vertically and horizontally in React-Native

Tags: react-native

I have 2 Views One view on the left that have 2 items aligned next to each other, and the other is on the right like this, and on IOS it's worse
[image]

The problem as you can see here the name is not align to the arrow, I can't figure what the reason is. Here is my code:

```
<View style={styles.header}>
   <View style={styles.leftHeader}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}>
         <ArrowLeft />
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <View>
         <Text style={styles.username}>{user && user.username}</Text>
      </View>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => setMoreModalVisible(true)}
        style={styles.twoDots}>
        <TwoDots />
      </TouchableOpacity>
   </View>
```

and here is the styling:

```
header: {
    paddingHorizontal: wp(3),
    flexDirection: 'row',
    marginTop: hp(2.5),
    marginBottom: hp(1),
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  leftHeader: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    textAlignVertical: 'center',
  },
  username: {
    fontFamily: semiBoldFont,
    fontSize: 15,
    paddingLeft: wp(3),
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the style of `<ArrowLeft />` component. There might be some padding or margin applied there.

Or provide us with a snack for you code so we can be able to help you.

Comment: The <ArrowLeft /> is just an svg image

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the height of the header because the `headerStyle` prop doesn't have a `height` prop.
You can follow the docs reference on this link:
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/headers#adjusting-header-styles

Another way to modify the header style you can set the `headerShown` prop to `false` and build your own header in the component where you can define the `view` height of your custom header, but be carefully because if you turn of the header in `react-navigation` then you have to use the `safeareaview` from `react-native-safe-area-context` because your screen will be slip up. On Android you don't take care about this.

A little code snipett for the example:

```
<Stack.Screen
  name="example"
  component={Component}
  options={{headerShown: false}}
/>

function Component() {
  const headerHeight = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 44 : 20

  return (
  <SafeAreaView edges={["top"]}>
    <View style={{height: headerHeight}}>
      // your custom header content
    </View>
  </SafeAreaView>
  )
}
```